# Max of the column in SharePoint (formula)

Tags: sharepoint, excel-formula, sharepoint-2013

have a simple list with column Name and Price.
I've inserted values:

```
Name | Price
-------------
A    |   3
-------------
B    |   30
```

I need to get the maximum of all Price values inserted before to make a check if price in inserted record is bigger than existing maximum (something like auction).

But =Price>MAX(Price) isn't working, cause it is checking only existing record. Is there ane agregation functions for my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharePoint Formula works only on the Current Item values. So you can't get the MAX price of all the item in the list in a formula.
You need to do that whith Programmation :

Event receiver : ItemAdding (using SharePoint Object Model Server side)

Or

JavaScript : override the **PreSaveAction()** function, to get the Max price and check with your value

Comment: Well, you've answered my question. Never worked with event recivers, rtf time :(

Comment: Can use CAML queries for it too i think

<Query>
    <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="particularcolumn" Ascending="FALSE" />
    </OrderBy>
</Query>

Comment: Yes you can use something like :`SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Price'/>";
            query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Price' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";
            query.RowLimit = 1;

            SPListItemCollection itemsCollection = mylist.GetItems(query);
            if (itemsCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                SPListItem TheMaxPriceItem = itemsCollection[0];
                //Do the stuff
            }`

Comment: And, to cancel the save of item, you can use : `properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                    properties.ErrorMessage ="message";
                    properties.Cancel = true;
                    return;`

Comment: Anyway there is no way to make it with SP Designer, and no Visual Studio for me atm :(

Comment: yes there is a way to do it without VisualStudio. You need to use JavaScript (JSOM) to dev you check logic (like in EventReceiver). You override the JS methode named : **PreSaveAction()**. You put your Javascript in the listForms with a Content Editor WebPart and voila ;)

Answer (score 0):

> SPListItem maxID = (from x in listCollection select x).Max();

This should work

Comment: I am sorry, but where should I execute this code? In formula wizard?